# Java JPanel Layout

Tags: java, swing

Im new in Java Swing, and want to make my layout, but can't do this

Look Now :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/raLS6.png]

Look I want :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikGgx.png]

Code Now :

```
JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    JLabel MoneyLabel = new JLabel(MoneyIcon);      
    MoneyLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    MoneyLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    MoneyLabel.setText("Money:" + CarMain.Money);

    JLabel MoneyClicksLabel = new JLabel();
    MoneyClicksLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    MoneyClicksLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    MoneyClicksLabel.setText("Money Clicks: " + CarMain.MoneyClicks);

    JLabel BoxesLabel = new JLabel(BoxLv9_10Icon);      
    BoxesLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    BoxesLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    BoxesLabel.setText("Boxes: " + CarMain.Boxes);

    JLabel BoxesClicksLabel = new JLabel();
    BoxesClicksLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    BoxesClicksLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    BoxesClicksLabel.setText("Boxes Clicks: " + CarMain.BoxesClicks);

    MainPanel.add(MoneyLabel);
    MainPanel.add(MoneyClicksLabel);
    MainPanel.add(jbtnMoney);
    MainPanel.add(BoxesLabel);
    MainPanel.add(BoxesClicksLabel);
    MainPanel.add(jbtnBoxes);
```

This is simple example of, what i want, becouse i'm building ingame shop, with 13 labels like these, in each tabbedpane window. How can i make it look, like in second picture, what I want?

Comment: Take a look at my solution below.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn the [Java Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) and follow them when posting code in the forum. Otherwise the forum syntax highlighting doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Im new in Java Swing, and want to make my layout, but can't do this

*Probably no single layout can suit everyone's needs. But combining several layouts can usually handle most scenarios.*

From the image you showed in the question. There is no need to write your own layout. You can always use sub panels to hold your components and set a specific layout for each sub panel to handle what you need for those individual areas.

- The reason for the alignment in your first attached image is because:

***JPanel*** uses ***FlowLayout*** as its default layout. Hence all the components added will appear in a linear fashion and tries to fill up the row as much as possible the panel's width can hold. Once exceeded the panel's width, the components will be pushed to the next row.

---

- If you want to achieve the alignment in the second attached image:

You may create a main panel to contain several sub-panels (see image below).
The red box is your main panel and you may continue to use the default FlowLayout.

Then add your components into sub-panels (orange boxes) before adding it to the main. You may then use ***BoxLayout***, ***FlowLayout*** or even ***GridBagLayout*** for the sub panels (orange boxes).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Artis Uljanovs, at night after work i will give a look at this to help you.

I recommend you already to read the following: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

You need some foundations on Java Layouts.